# spring batch - export data to csv with FlatFileItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I try to export csv file but  I found error , all value is set to one column and not in two or three columns and this is example of output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDrDJ.png)

code java for export file:

```
    public writeFile(List<Test> tests) throws Exception {
FlatFileItemWriter<Test> flatFileItemWriter
                = new FlatFileItemWriter<Test>();
        flatFileItemWriter.setResource
                (new FileSystemResource
                        ("/data/outputData.csv"));

        flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(getDelimitedLineAggregator());
          flatFileItemWriter.open(new ExecutionContext());
        flatFileItemWriter.write(tests);
        flatFileItemWriter.close();

        return flatFileItemWriter; 

}

    private DelimitedLineAggregator<Test> getDelimitedLineAggregator() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Test> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Test>();
        beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"Id", "typeTest1", "typeTest2"});

        DelimitedLineAggregator<Test > aggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Test>();
        aggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        aggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);
        return aggregator;
    }
```

file is exported but output is not good, all data for one line in one columns, how to make data one line in multiple columns, also I found even error in header values when I set headers, all values in one columns.

Thanks for advanced

Comment: Looks like it's not an export problem - it is an import problem. I thonk you didn't choose delimiter when opened a file

Comment: where is the best delimiter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image: Excel configuration screen capture]

This might happen while opening the file in Excel.